# How to hide back button of React Native navigator

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, react-native

I have made a login button which will jump to main-ui. I don't want people to see the back button at top-left position of navigator's default style.

It seems that `NavigatorIOS` has no suitable API to use. Can you give me some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html).  I recommend using it in conjunction with [React Native Navbar](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar).

With Navbar, you can pass in the right and left button components... Or just make them an empty view, if they shouldn't be visible.  The property is `leftButton` and `rightButton`.

The navigator example on the React docs should get you started:

```js
<Navigator
    initialRoute={{name: 'My First Scene', index: 0}}
    renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
      <MySceneComponent
        name={route.name}
        onForward={() => {
          var nextIndex = route.index + 1;
          navigator.push({
            name: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
            index: nextIndex,
          });
        }}
        onBack={() => {
          if (route.index > 0) {
            navigator.pop();
          }
        }}
      />
    }
  />
```

Now in the definition of `MySceneComponent` you would include displaying NavBar:

```js
const MySceneComponent = (props) => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
      <NavigationBar
        title={titleConfig}
        rightButton={BUTTON_OR_NOT} 
        {...props} />
      {props.children}
    </View>
);
```

Of course you will want to abstract your navigation bits perhaps into a component which displays the navigation bar around it as I have shown above with the display of `{children}`.  You will further want to pass the `route` and `navigation` information into Navbar so it can display the page information and make it so that clicking on the back button calls `navigator.pop()`, which is what I did by passing on `props` via `{...props}`.